# Returning field value based on expression on another field using QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, features, qgis-expression

I want to return the value from one field (`"Number"`) for the feature with the most recent timestamp (`"Time"`) from within the current layer (`'mylayer'`). Or what's the number of the last previous feature I created?

I can do this using the expression below but I am concerned about it finding the layer and there must be a better way to do this.

```
attribute(  
    get_feature('mylayer', 'Time', maximum("Time")), 
        'Number'
         )
```

Comment: This is the third day I read your question and I still don't really understand it, despite it being clear on the first glance. Can you provide some more details on your workflow and layers?

Comment: An expression that returns a value from one field based on a search performed on another. I have tree numbers and survey times stamps, so before the current feature being added what was is the number of the most recent tree added. The expression I have written works but it relies on finding the layer even though it is all working for one layer.

Comment: So I want to know value A, where B is the newest entry? Is your `time` field actually of datetime type?

Comment: Yes, I used a datetime format field.